# Android library project debugging quickly

Tags: android, android-library, android-debug

I am developing a library project. Right now my debugging process is something like this :

- Make some changes in library code
- build it into an aar file
- use the aar file in main app project as new library module
- then debug the code changes in lib code.

As you can see it's a long process and takes a lot of time to debug library. What is the proper way for library development using android studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way:

- Add library module in same project directory like app folder : File-> new-> new module -> Android Library.
- Add your library module name in setting.gradle (eg. include ':app',':xyz') : should be added automatically
- Right click on your main app folder-> open module settings -> add your library as dependency to "app" (it's under module dependency).
- Go to build.gradle file of your main project, add module like compile project (':xyz')

No need to create aar , just make changes in lib module and Run your main project and debug it .

Hope this will help you !

Comment: This is good idea. Saved a lot of time. I have edited answer to make it clearer.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of sharing code. What if you have a second project which needs to use the same library? Are you going to duplicate your library code in each?

Answer (score 0):

I would include a demo-app project in parallel to library project:

```
//  /settings.gradle
include ':app', ':lib'

//  /app/build.gradle
depencency {
    compile project(':lib')
}
```